# SSH в Python, paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, sudo, paramiko

Видел другие обсуждения но полезного не обнаружил

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.168.0.13', username='aa', password='aa')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo reboot")
stdin.write('aa\n')
stdin.flush()
data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
print(data)
ssh.close()
```

Этот код должен вроде выполнять 'sudo reboot' и соответственно отправлять пароль 'aa' что бы sudo выполнился, но этого не происходит, почему? Сам код выполняется без ошибок

UPD: Я проверил, он подключается и "входит"

Comment: Вероятно, потому что для ввода пароля требуется терминал, а вы никакого терминала не предоставили. Попробуйте `ssh.exec_command(..., get_pty=True)`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, это сработало. Напишите как ответ

Comment: Не страдайте ерундой, настройте доступ ssh через ключ rsa

Answer (score 0):

> Вероятно, потому что для ввода пароля требуется терминал, а вы никакого терминала не предоставили. Попробуйте ssh.exec_command(..., get_pty=True) [andreymal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ij9dgAXhfi8)

Answer (score 0):

**Попробуйте следующий код:**

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(...)

channel = сlient.get_transport().open_session()
channel.get_pty()
channel.settimeout(5)
channel.exec_command('sudo reboot')
channel.send(password+'\n')
print channel.recv(1024)

channel.close()
client.close()
```